# Draw line in mapbox android

Tags: java, android, mapbox, mapbox-android, mapbox-marker

I am developing an android application with Mapbox where I am supposed to mark the map based on some value received from the accelerometer. I was able to put marks like this

[image: this]

and this

[image: this]

I tried the line layer also but it is marking the complete area like this

[image: this]

Is there any other option to mark line only selected areas?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, what you want to do is called "Draw a GeoJSON line".

Here is the link to the documentation: it should be easy to follow along.

- [Draw a GeoJSON line](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/examples/draw-a-geojson-line/)